# "Object 'direction' not found" with dendrogram in ggraph package

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph, bioconductor, ggraph

I try to plot a dendrogram with the `ggraph` package but, it's ok with `geom_edge_diagonal()` but not with `geom_edge_elbow()`

**Packages**

```
library(phyloseq)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
```

**Getting data**

The file ps.rds is available here

https://github.com/spholmes/F1000_workflow/tree/master/data

```
ps <- readRDS("ps.rds")

EdgeList <- phy_tree(ps)$edge
Tree <- graph_from_edgelist(EdgeList, directed = TRUE)
```

**Plotting**

```
ggraph(Tree, 'dendrogram') +
  geom_edge_diagonal()
```

[image]

This code works but the plot is not very beautiful.

And now :

```
ggraph(Tree, 'dendrogram', circular = TRUE) +
  geom_edge_elbow()

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'direction' not found
```

So I have some questions :

1. Why it doesn't work yhereas it works for the other dendrogram ?
2. What is direction ? In the package documentation, it is said that direction is "automatically set" https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggraph/versions/0.1.1/topics/geom_edge_elbow
3. Can I found something useful for plotting in the ps object ?

**EDIT** after F. Privé comment

Yes, it's possible to mix `dendrogram` and `circular`.

```
ggraph(Tree, 'dendrogram', circular = TRUE) +
  geom_edge_diagonal()
```

[image]

Comment: When I play around your example, I get the error "Circular layout only applicable to tree and DAG layout". Are you sure you can use `layout = 'dendrogram'` with `circular = TRUE`?

Answer (score 2):

For some reasons that are too involved to discuss here, `geom_edge_elbow` currently only supports dedrogram/hclust objects and not igraph objects.

I'll probably have figured a way around that for the next release